# How to calculate total paid amount for each id in various stages and reducing the paid amount after each stage in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`.

- `TableA` has total demand (column name -> amount) split into various rows.
- `TableB` has supply numbers (column name -> amount).

I want to split the supply numbers and assign them against each row in `TableA` for each id (column name -> number).

Sample data for `TableA` and `TableB` are as follows:

**TableA**:

```
row number  amount
-------------------
1     x       10
2     y        5
3     z       120
4     z        80
5     z         5
```

**TableB**:

```
number  amount
---------------
  x       5 
  y       15
  z       200
```

Required output is :

```
row number  amount  paid
-------------------------
1     x        10     5
2     y         5     5
3     z       120   120
4     z        80    80
5     z         5     0
```

As of now we are using the below mentioned code which is very ugly and does not give good performance as we are using recursive `cte`'s to do this job as our system was SQL Server 2008 R2 and we had no option but now our software has been upgraded to SQL Server 2012 and I know same can be achieved using sum function with order by in over clause. But I do not know how?

```
with cte as 
(
    select 
        a.row, a.number, a.amount,
        b.amount as total
    from 
        tableA as a
    left join 
        tableB as b on a.number = b.number
),
cte1 as 
(
    select 
        row, number, amount, total,
        case 
           when amount - total < 0 then amount else total 
        end as paid,
        case 
           when amount - total < 0 then amount else total 
        end as totalpaid
    from 
        cte
    where 
        row = 1

    union all

    select 
        b.row, b.number, b.amount, b.total,
        case
           when b.amount - (b.total - (case when b.number = a.number then a.totalpaid else 0 end)) < 0 then b.amount else (b.total - (case when b.number = a.number then a.totalpaid else 0 end)) end,
           case when b.amount - (b.total - (case when b.number = a.number then a.totalpaid else 0 end)) < 0 then b.amount else (b.total - (case when b.number = a.number then a.totalpaid else 0 end)) end + ((case when b.number = a.number then a.totalpaid else 0 end))
    from 
        cte1 as a
    inner join 
        cte as b on b.row = a.row + 1
)
select 
    row, number, amount, paid
from 
    cte1
```

Can someone tell me how to write the above code efficiently in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
WITH cte as
(
    SELECT a.row,
        a.number, 
        a.amount,
        b.amount AS totalPaid,
        SUM(a.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.number ORDER BY row ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS totalAmount
            FROM (VALUES (1,'x',10),(2,'y',5),(3,'z',120),(4,'z',80),(5,'z',5)) AS a(row, number, amount)
            LEFT JOIN (VALUES ('x',5),('y',15),('z',200)) as b(number, amount) ON a.number = b.number
)
SELECT row, number, amount, CASE WHEN totalPaid >= totalAmount THEN amount ELSE CASE WHEN amount - totalAmount + totalPaid < 0 THEN 0 ELSE amount - totalAmount + totalPaid END END AS paid
    FROM cte;
```

And please give me feedback about correctness and performance improvement.

Comment: This works like a charm with performance. Simply brilliant. Thanks